# Google Analytics API Quota for several clients

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I tried searching but I didn't find any useful resource that would answer my question.

I'm trying to develop a service for my costumers where I will need to connect to their analytics data and combine with information of other services that I already provide. However, with the quota of the API request, how can I get it to work with several costumers?

I mean, the limitation is 10.000 requests per month, and I will probably make around 40-50 requests per day per costumer. That means that if I get more than 7 costumers to use it I would reach the monthly quota. What is the best approach to make this scalable?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ask your clients to authorize your app with their respective Accounts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confused a little about the [Google Analtyics api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/limits-quotas) limits.

[Managment api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/), and [metadata api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/devguide) have a limit of 10,000 requests per day.  10 requests per second.

The [Core reporting api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) is 10,000 requests per day per User and or (View (used to be profile)) and 50,000 requests per application.  You can request that that 50k be extended.  But you need to show that there arnt a lot of errors comming from your application.

It might be a good idea to also send send either Userip or [quotaUser](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#quotaUser) with all over your requests this will ensure that each of your users gets 10k requests each day. If you dont send quotaUser or UserIp then google lumps them all under the same quota user and they they are as a group limited to the 10k.  This may or may not be a problem if you can ensure that sevral users wont be requesting the same data from the same view (used to be profile)

Another thing you should remember is that nextlinks count twards the limit as well so you should either try refine your requests so that you dont get to many rows back or set [max-results](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#maxResults) high enough that you dont get to many nextlinks.

You can read more about how and why you should use QuotaUser here [Google Analtyics QuotaUser](http://daimto.com/google-analytics-quota/?rel=nofollow)

Comment: @DalmTo, when you say 50,000 per app, is it the same as project on google api console? So if, for example, I have 5 users using their 10,000 requests per user/view, I would reach this 50k quota, right? And the alternatives to attend new users would be requesting a larger quota and/or having multiple applications? Thanks!

Comment: Yes its your app. that has the 50k.   Yes 5 users using different views(profile) could hit the limit.  Just ask Google to extend your quota.  It doesn't cost anything as far as I know.   BTW I have some huge accounts and have only hit the daily 10k quota when I'm personally testing.  Its really hard.  You shouldn't worry to much

Comment: @DalmTo, thanks for the info! You convinced me not to worry with the 10K in your first post :) my worry now is with the 50K, but since we have workarounds, that shouldn't be a problem (mainly now that the solution is not yet being used by that many users)! Thank you once again!

Comment: hitting the 50 k really isn't a problem.  Remember old data doesn't change you don't need to request last weeks data again if you already have it.  If you do it the 50k all you have to do is contact Google and they will extend the quota as long as you can show that there aren't to many errors in your app.  Remember we are talking requests not rows returned hear.

Answer (score 1):

The quota is 10,000 per day per profile.

You should be fine especially if each of your clients has a separate profile.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v2/limits-quotas#core_reporting